# Are there any math contests paid in Bitcoin?

Tags: money

Are there any hard math problems or math contests that have rewards paid in Bitcoin?

Comment: Sure, Bitcoin mining. /s

Comment: No I mean if you solve some important problem like Goldbach's conjecture, or the traveling salesman problem is there any group or website that can pay you for the solution in say $1000 dollars worth of Bitcoin  transferable to your computer?

Comment: There are some mathematics problems for which people have offered monetary or other tangible rewards, see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/66084/open-problems-with-monetary-rewards. But I have never heard of one with a reward payable in Bitcoin.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Math contests.

Comment: If some group had a math problem as a contest might they be agreeable to 'paying' a reward in bitcoin? Has any group ever thought about contests with monetary rewards paid in bitcoin?

Comment: Instead of worry so much about if a question is off-topic why not say we can't answer it 'here' but why not try 'such and such'..

Comment: Concerning the Beale conjecture ; he is a banker and amateur mathematician ( I Think). He or some associated group has offered 1 million dollars for a solution. Maybe he could offer an equivalent value in Bitcoin. Also the Millennium Math prizes could be partly offered in Bitcoin. These are just suggestions whether this is off topic or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a site where one can submit bounties for proofs of theorems in Coq formal proof management system, and get paid in bitcoin:

- [proofmarket.org](https://proofmarket.org/)

Additionally there are other sites that have done competitions in the past:

- [mathgate.info treasure hunt](https://mathgate.info/)

Another project in development (but at the moment not specifically tied to bitcoin) is [ProofPeer](http://www.proofpeer.net/index.html)

Additional information about these proof markets can be found in this article:  http://blogchain.fr/programmarket-en/